# How to use multipart dataon json server for react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, nsjsonserialization, json-server

I am writing post method with video and images files on react. But i used multipart/form-data format for json-server but it does not work. I can't get the data I want.
What is it my mistake ? Can you help me ?
this is my post method.

```js
const ApiUrl = "http://localhost:8000/";

export const sshOpenServiceRequest = async (jsonData) => {
    return axios.post(ApiUrl + `serviceList`, jsonData,
      {
        headers: {
          ContentType: "multipart/form-data",
        }
      })
    .then((response) => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return false;
    });
};

this is my submit method
 const handleSubmit = async () => {
    //const isValid = checkValid();
    //if (isValid) {
      setIsSubmitting(true);

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("materialCode", matCode);
      formData.append("channel", channel);
      formData.append("warehouseUnitCode", wareHouseUnit);

      for (const key in photos) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(photos, key)) {
          const element = photos[key];
          formData.append(`images`, element);
        }
      }

      for (const key in videos) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(videos, key)) {
          const element = videos[key];
          formData.append(`videos`, element);
        }
      }
      try {
        const result = await sshOpenServiceRequest(formData);
        console.log(result);
        if (result.data.success) {
          //history.push("/ssh-list/");
          notify("Form isteği başarılı");
        } else {
          notify("Form isteği başarısız");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        notify("Form isteği başarısız");
      }

      setIsSubmitting(true);
    //}
  };
```

Comment: Guessing from your title your server is expecting `application/json` but is receiving the `multipart/form-data` content type. The latter is the correct way for sending images and video's. Please share the backend code which receives the call to `localhost:8000/serviceList` and meanwhile check if you'v implemented support for the necessary content type.

Comment: Hello Emiel, first thank your answer. This code working on my normal webapi backend. My problem is not this. I want to work this code  with JASON-SERVER api but when i tried with json-server api i got this error.

Comment: I have no idea what your "normal" WebAPI backend is and why it's working there. Well, you've got the wrong tool for the job. [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) is a *mocking* tool for creating REST API's which uses the JSON format for sending and receiving data. JSON is not a suitable format to send images in, unless you convert the images to Base64 strings and then send them. But I still suggest not using JSON and using the `multipart/form-data` content type as that *does* support sending files (read: images).

Comment: Yes, i must use multipart/form-data but json-api very complex about this state. I dont know maybe i can't

Comment: My suggestion is to not use [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) because it simply does not do what you need. What you do need is unclear because we don't know what you're trying to make. Have you looked into other frameworks like [Express JS](https://codex.so/handling-any-post-data-in-express) which can handle `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: You are right but I must use json-server because I am frontend developer and I try my codes with json server until web api comes. I will control Express Js but i know a little. I dont think about to with video an photo.